# ValueError when Integrating a Function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm quite new to Python, so this is probably quite a basic question. I'm receiving the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

on my following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
%matplotlib inline

x = y = z = np.linspace (0, 5)

#Define Integrals
P = 67.6*(np.sqrt (0.3*((1+z)**3)) + 0.7)

import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad

A = quad(lambda x: ((1+x)*((P)**-3)), z, sp.oo)
B = quad(lambda y: ((1+y)*((P)**-3)), 0, sp.oo)

D = (P/67.6)*(a/b)

plt.plot(z, D, 'r')

plt.xlabel ('$z$'); plt.ylabel ('$D_+$')

plt.savefig('LinearGrowthFactor.png',dpi = 400)
```

I've searched for an answer for a while now but I haven't found anything that I can both understand and actually apply to my code. The error is appearing on the line

```
A = quad(lambda x: ((1+x)*((P)**-3)), z, sp.oo)
```

so the same error will likely appear in the line below as well.

EDIT:
Here's the full error I'm receiving.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-94d843ab23dd> in <module>()
 13 from scipy.integrate import quad
 14 
---> 15 A = quad(lambda x: ((1+x)*((P)**-3)), z, sp.oo)
 16 B = quad(lambda y: ((1+y)*((P)**-3)), 0, sp.oo)
 17 

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
314     if (weight is None):
315         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 316                        points)
317     else:
318         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
363 def _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points):
364     infbounds = 0
--> 365     if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
366         pass   # standard integration
367     elif (b == Inf and a != -Inf):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Did you already check out other questions with that error here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Why are you passing a `sympy` object as the `b` paramater to `quad`?  That's supposed to be a scalar.

Comment: You need to give us more of the stack trace.  The error is probably occurring inside `quad`, as a result of your arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I've searched both this website and others.

Comment: @slothwayne: and what did you find? There are plenty of results here on SO for the error message.

Comment: I read a lot about boolean operators but I couldn't find anything I could apply because I'm so inexperienced when it comes to coding.